# If statement based on a total

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel but have enjoyed trying new things with the program.  I'm trying to figure out if I can have one cell read something based on the standing of other cells.  For example:

If `g10 = 6` then `h14` will read either unacceptable, acceptable, recognized or exemplary based on a the scale shown below.

- 0-1 unacceptable
- 2-4 acceptable
- 5-7 recognized
- 8-9 exemplary

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are a dozen ways to do any one thing in Excel and this is no different. I'll show you two.

First you can do this with a bunch of IF statements

```
=IF(G10<=2,"Unacceptable",IF(G10<=4,"Acceptable",IF(G10<=7,"Recognized",IF(G10<=9,"Exemplary","Too Good"))))
```

You can see this is pretty good but it means you need to rewrite your formula if anything changes in your scale.

The other way is to use VLookups.

I put these values in the range A1:B10

```
0   Unaceptable
1   Unaceptable
2   Acceptable
3   Acceptable
4   Acceptable
5   Recognized
6   Recognized
7   Recognized
8   Exemplary
9   Exemplary
```

Then used this formula for the lookup

```
=VLOOKUP(G10,A1:B10,2,FALSE)
```

Where

```
=VLOOKUP(D16 <~~ The value to use to look up
 ,A1:B10     <~~ The range in which you're doing the lookup. The lookup is always performed on the left most column. Any other columns included in the range are available to be return values.
 ,2          <~~ Column from range A1:B10 to return from the Vlookup function
 ,FALSE      <~~ Whether or not to do approximate matching. You more than likely always want exact matching so this will usually be false
 )
```

If you will be using this in more than one cell and/or are copy/pasting it around you can lock in the lookup range using `$`. i.e.  `=VLOOKUP(G10,$A$1:$B$10,2,FALSE)` These will not be relative references if you use the `$` sign. You can put this in by hitting <kbd>F4</kbd>

One step better than this is to use named ranges though. This means while you have our grading scale highlighted in `A1:B10` you go to that text box to the left of the formula bar and type `MyGradingScale` and they now you can refer to that range by name.

```
=VLOOKUP(G10,MyGradingScale,2,FALSE)
```

You can then use this formula in lots of places and upgate it in one place. Go to Formulas>Name Manager on the ribbon to change the reference.

Comment: Ah, I guess you don't need the `AND` statements here. Me having logic on a Monday morning = FALSE

Comment: that would work too. My way isn't set up to handle negative numbers; using `AND` is. Like I said...a dozen ways to get the same answer

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple, depending on what version of Excel you're using.

A simple, `IF(AND())` formula should work here

Try:

```
=IF(AND(A1>=0,A1<=1), "Unacceptable", NEXT TEST HERE)
```

That should get you started, just use nested IF(AND()) statements.